# Python: sympy, I cannot solve the hyperbolic sine equation

Tags: python, sympy

I have one problem that the sympy module is not solve the following equation.

```
import sympy as sy
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy import *

deld = Symbol('deld')
sinh = sy.sinh
a = (-0.00026478*deld - 1.75012e-9*sinh(0.62831 - 62831.85307*deld) + 1.750123e-9*sinh(62831.85307*deld - 0.62831) + 2.64786e-9)
b = (0.00026478*deld + 1.75012e-9*sinh(0.62831 - 62831.85307*deld) - 1.750123e-9*sinh(62831.85307*deld - 0.62831) - 2.34686e-9)
c= -1

d = sy.solve((a/b)+c, deld)


print (d)
```

I want to get the numerical value of 'deld'. But python does not solve this equation with memory error. I already tired to solve this problem with 128GB RAM, But it was failed.

Please any help. Thank you.

Comment: Hi,
Can you try to break this down into small equations like- a,b,c,d and then compute your result ? That will help you find out where is the problem

Comment: I edit my equation following your comment, If any request I will fix my code. Thank you

Comment: With the wide variety of numbers in your equation, a numerical approach instead of a symbolic approach may better.

Comment: Note that since `c = -1`, you actually can solve for `a - b = 0`. Since a and b have the same argument in the sinh part of their equations, you can simplify the `a - b` expression. That simplified expression may be easier to solve for.

Comment: Thank you for your mention. What is the mean of numerical approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a numerical solution then in SymPy it is better to use `nsolve`. The numerical problem that you have posed is extremely ill conditioned so many numerical solvers will struggle. It is also not something that can easily be solved symbolically (which is what you are asking for by calling `solve` rather than `nsolve`).

Plotting the function reveals that there is a root in the range `[0.6e-5, 0.7e-5]`. We can ask `nsolve` to find that root:

```
In [62]: nsolve((a/b+c), deld, [0.6e-5, 0.7e-5])
Out[62]: 6.50904815581165e-6
```